# shiny, timevis and html templates

Tags: html, r, shiny

i'm having a problem displaying a timevis in an html block in shiny.

the following code is the base example which works:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  timevisOutput("timeline")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    timevis(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

however if i use an html template and try to display the content this does not appear. here is sample code

```
   library(shiny)
    library(timevis)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
            tags$div(id="page-content-wrapper", 
                    timevisOutput("timeline")
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
      timevis(data)
    })



  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the html containing the reference

```
<div id=" timeline " class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100%;height:200px;"></div>
```

any idea why this happens? am i missing something? (i.e. appropriate inclusion of js libs in either the app's header or html file?) if anyone has a working example with htmlwidgets, that could be an alternative too, but i cannot get anything to work at the moment

suggestions very welcome! thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce with shiny_1.0.3, timevis_0.4, R_3.3.2, win7

Comment: Oh man, I gave the bounty because OP emailed me and I said I'm too busy to check it out. So I wanted to help by giving a bounty... maybe I should have spent 5 min trying to reproduce :)

Comment: @DeanAttali That's a mistake new investors often make :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. The only reason I can think of could be the out-dated packages:
Here are the packages loaded for my session:

```
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11    digest_0.6.12   rprojroot_1.2   mime_0.5        R6_2.2.1        backports_1.1.0 xtable_1.8-2   
 [8] jsonlite_1.5    magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.10   stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.5   tools_3.4.0     stringr_1.2.0  
[15] htmlwidgets_0.8 httpuv_1.3.3    yaml_2.1.14     rsconnect_0.8   compiler_3.4.0  htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.16
```

HTML code produced by shiny app is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
<script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.0.3];htmlwidgets[0.8];vis[4.16.1];timeline[0.4];timevis-binding[0.4];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>
<script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
<script src="htmlwidgets-0.8/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<link href="vis-4.16.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="vis-4.16.1/vis.min.js"></script>
<link href="timeline-0.4/timevis.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="timevis-binding-0.4/timevis.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div id="timeline" class="timevis html-widget html-widget-output" style="width:100%; height:auto; ">
      <div class="btn-group zoom-menu">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg zoom-in" title="Zoom in">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg zoom-out" title="Zoom out">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @lorenzov could you please confirm that after updating your packages, your original problem goes away? If you can confirm I will award the bounty

Comment: i'm afraid not, as everyone seems to have focused on the example given (which does work already, but obviously i've been bad in explaining things, so i'll add more info

Comment: the bounty is expiring so I will have to award it because this answer is correct given the question. You can write a brand new question if you need more help, just make sure you give a reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

I have to thank my colleague @ZachA as my question was not entirely accurate, but there is very little documented out there, so it may be useful to others.

in order to add custom html to shiny apps there are several ways as documented on the R sites and articles (i.e. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html or http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html).

there are tow ways to include files:

includehtml('yourfile') and htmlTemplate('yourfile')

this is where the problem is as the way the html is rendered is different and the inclusion or exclusion of headers in the source html files caused my problem, especially if you start mixing the two ways.

in my case using htmlTemplate seem to be the root cause; changing the call to file to includehtml solved it.

here is a bit of the code to explain

```
  ui <- bootstrapPage(
tags$head(
  tags$script(src='js/custom.js')
  ,tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href ='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
  ,tags$script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.20.0/vis.min.js')
  ,tags$script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js')
  ,tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href ='css/style.css')
  ,tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href ='css/myvis.css')

  ),
myuser = verbatimTextOutput("s_user"),
tags$div(id="wrapper",
    tags$div(class="overlay"),
    tags$nav(class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top", id="sidebar-wrapper", role="navigation", includeHTML("./sidebar.html")),
    tags$div(id="page-content-wrapper", htmlTemplate("./main.html")),

    tags$div(class="container",
        tags$div(class="row",
                 tabsetPanel(type="pills",
                     tabPanel("Overview", 
                              htmlTemplate("html_template/overview.html")
                              ),
                     tabPanel("Streams", 
                              includeHTML("html_template/streams.html")
                     ),

                     tabPanel("Budget", 
                              includeHTML("html_template/budget.html")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Status", 
                              htmlTemplate("html_template/status.html")
                     ),


                     tabPanel("Milestones", 
                              includeHTML("html_template/milestones.html")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Risks", 
                              htmlTemplate("html_template/risks.html")
                     )
                   )

             )

    )
  )
)
```

as you can see using the bootstrapPage layout and adding the various libraries helped me resolve it (the stream.html file in the code). at the end, for maximum flexibility we coded the javascript inside the template and use shinyjs to populate the json object to draw the viz.